# What is the right way to add an `if` to a generator expression in Python?

Tags: python, loops

this is my code :

```
s = ''.join('%s: %s </br>' % (a,getattr(user, a) ) for a in dir(user))
```

and i want to add a `if` in this code , so i write :

```
s = ''.join('%s: %s </br>' % (a,getattr(user, a) if !a.index('__') ) for a in dir(user))
```

i think it is not right ,

what is the right way to add a `if`  in the for loop ,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the condition to evaluate on each iteration through the loop at the end, like this:

```
s = ''.join('%s: %s </br>' % 
               (a,getattr(user, a)) for a in dir(user) if '__' not in a
           )
```

Edit: Sorry, fixed the parentheses to the appropriate nesting.

Edited: Changed the conditional (didn't even pay attention to it before, thanks Falmarri.

Comment: Also, instead of `!a.index('__')` you should use something more pythonic, like `if '__' not in a`

Comment: `if !a.index('__') ` --- > `if not a.index('__') `

Comment: str not in a is the natural pythonic way to do this (edited answer to reflect this) - it just reads like English.

Comment: -2 Firstly, ! is a syntax error. Secondly, str.index('__') is not only not "Pythonic", it doesn't work. If '__' is not in the string, an exception will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `for iterated in interator if condition(iterated)`, so you need to move the `if` after the `dir(user)`:

```
s = ''.join('%s: %s </br>'
        % (a,getattr(user, a) for a in dir(user) if !a.index('__') ))
```

Comment: -2 `!` is a syntax error. An exception will be raised when str.index fails.